# Getting value as DateTime, but displaying as DateTime.Year in DropDownList (with LINQ)

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datetime, drop-down-menu

In the database, I have a table 'Years', that contains columns for 'YearId', 'YearStart' and 'YearEnd' (don't ask me why, its not my database).

I need to populate an asp:DropDownList with the different year values in the table, ie. I need the dropdown to be like:

```
//pseudocode
<select>
    <option>2010</option>
    <option>2011</option>
    ..etc..
</select>
```

But since the 'YearStart' and 'YearEnd' are stored in DateTime format, I'm getting this:

```
//pseudocode
<select>
    <option>1/1/2010 12:00:00 AM</option>
    <option>1/1/2011 12:00:00 AM</option>
    ..etc..
</select>
```

Here is how I am currently populating the DropDownList:

```
dropDownList.DataSource = DataContext.Years;
dropDownList.DataValueField = "YearId";
dropDownList.DataTextField = "YearStart";
dropDownList.DataBind();
```

Basically, I need the dropDownList.DataTextField to be in DateTime.Year form, ie:

```
//pseudocode
dropDownList.DataTextField = ("YearStart").Year;
```

So what would be the best way to populate the dropDownList and achieve what I need?

Comment: Is YearStart and YearEnd in DateTime Format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try including `DataTextFormatString`

```
dropDownList.DataTextFormatString = "{0:YYYY}";
```

or

you can tweak the DataSource like this

```
dropDownList.DataSource = DataContext.Years.Select(y => new {y.YearID, YearStart = y.YearStart.Year})
                                    .ToList();
```

Comment: This won't work because DataValueField and DataTextField will not be able to resolve from anonymous type

Comment: @Arthur they sure can as long as the property names match.

Comment: Well they don't match in the sample you've posted originally.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you don't want to change the data source itself, I suspect you'd use:

```
dropDownList.DataTextField = "YearStart.Year";
```

Basically you provide a binding *path*, not necessarily just a single property name.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your data binding code to just: (`using System.Linq` of course)

```
dropDownList.DataSource = DataContext.Years.Select(d => d.Year);
dropDownList.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all LINQy but I'd just do:
dropDownList.DataTextFormatString =  {0:yyyy};

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextformatstring.aspx